# Can I continue to use American express card during notice period?

Tags: germany, startup, benefits, expenses

I have an <strike>American express credit card</strike> Mastercard from my employer which I haven't used. I want to know if I can use it without any consequences before my notice period is over? I'm thinking of using it for stuff like train tickets, restaurant bills, hotels, books, and maybe clothing (within reason of course). Also, can I keep books I bought using my employers credit card?

#### Edit because I mistook my company Mastercard for the American express card:

My contract says *You receive 50 EUR per month as a tax-free allowance on your "given" MasterCard. You can use it to pay for your sports activities or just go shopping.*. I have never taken advantage of this benefit because I was only given an American express credit card which is for travel and business expenses.

Comment: Likely that violates your company's rules for usage of the card, and may result in termination with cause before the end of your notice. You will still be on the hook for any charges. Use your own credit card for your personal stuff.

Comment: What did your company *say* it should be used for? Surely they didn't just hand you a credit card with no rules.

Comment: Thanks @JonCuster. I won't then. Even though my contract does say this: *You receive 50 EUR per month as a tax-free allowance on your "givve" MasterCard. You can
use it to pay for your sports activities or just go shopping.*. And I have never taken advantage of this benefit.

Comment: @nvoigt. I reread my contract and the American express card has restrictions: *You receive an American Express credit card for travel and business expenses that is not
charged to your private account.*.

Comment: @Duzii2 - That is super important information that should be edited into your question (and just for accuracy, this implies that you're not talking about an American Express card).  Because that completely changes the answer (and the tenor of the answers)

Comment: @JustinCave, I mistook the American express card for the "givve" MasterCard.

Comment: That changes things. I might suspect that the 50 EUR per month does not roll over and accumulate...

Comment: _"for stuff like train tickets, restaurant bills, hotels, books, and maybe clothing"_ how far do you think you can go on 50 EUR? I'd be surprised if this is a benefit which accumulates, but rather you need to actual spend it in a month or lose it (doesn't roll-over to the next month).

Comment: "Also, can I keep books I bought using my employers credit card?" While technically company property, in my experience, employers are unlikely to care about low-value items like books; it likely depends on the size of the company. I've even been allowed to keep work laptops after being laid off.

Comment: Based on your questions it looks like you have an attitude that future employers may not consider a plus.  You may want to be absolutely certain that your activity here cannot be traced back to you personally.

Answer (score 5):

> Can I continue to use American express card during notice period?

This is a bad idea.  There will be consequences for using the card, especially if it is for personal items and not company use.  The company will likely go after you if you misuse the card.  Just return the card to the company and serve your notice period.

> Also, can I keep books I bought using my employers credit card?

If they were bought using company funds for company use, they likely belong to the company.  Return these to the company before your notice period is over.

Serving a notice period doesn't give you carte blanche to act like a thief.

***Edit to address your edit***

If you have never taken advantage of any company perk/benefit (not just the Mastercard), your notice period is probably not the best time to start doing so.  Even if you insist on doing so, you should check the company policy on the Mastercard or whatever perk/benefit you intend to start using during your notice period.  Some companies rescind specific perks/benefits the moment the employee resigns.

Comment: Though if there are specific books you want to keep, it's generally not a big deal to ask for permission to keep them.  I've had several heavily used reference books that had a bunch of my own annotations over the years and no employer has ever had a problem with me keeping those.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer, it may change your answer.

Comment: @Duzii2 updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** - There will absolutely be consequences, even after you've left the company can go after you for inappropriate charges on its credit cards.

> ...which I haven't used

So why would you want to start using it now? Do you not think that might look rather suspicious?

> I'm thinking of using it for stuff like train tickets, restaurant bills, hotels, books, and maybe clothing (within reason of course).

Unless your employer needs you to purchase these things without which you would be unable to do your job, then no. This is fraud. Your employer will have extremely clear guidelines what you can use your company issued card for.

> can I keep books I bought using my employers credit card?

No, they don't belong to you, they belong to the company. This would be theft.

Furthermore this question probably says more than you want it to about the motivations behind it.

**Following the questions edit**

The only reasonable answer now is to check with your boss <s>or HR department</s> as no-one here can know what your corporate policy says around the use of this 'other' card. I maintain it is still not a good look though, given as you've never used it before.

Comment: I updated my answer. My company's mastercard does allow me to use it for personal expenses. I mistook the American express card for it.

Comment: It's a startup without a HR department.

Answer (score 1):

If you exceed the 50 EUR limit and no one in the company notices it before you leave the company you will still be on the hook for the expenses.  When the company notices the illegal expenses they can send you a bill for them, and threaten to sue you if you do not pay up.

Answer (score 1):

Re-read your employment contract.

Based on your last edit, it sounds like your employer gives you a 50 EUR per month benefit (which again based on your last edit you can spend as you please). The critical question is does your contract say that you can carry over any unused balance from one month to the next?

If you are allowed to carry over the balance, then you probably have a significant amount accumulated / which you can spend. If not then you can probably only spend 50 EUROs.

You may also wish to talk with HR to clarify these details / find out what your accumulated balance is.

The critical point I am making is that:

- If you are entitled to spend it as you wish, then do so.
- However if not, then you should stick to the company policy.

Violating the policy is likely theft and may have consequences.

Comment: Theres' no HR department. It's a startup.